How to generate an OAuth 2 refresh token
I am trying to connect to the Google Ads API, so I will be able to manage campaigns and apply rules to them but to maintain a connection I need an OAuth Refresh Token. In the Google documentation, it says to install the OAuth2l but I was not able to install it.
Is there an alternative way to generate a refresh token?
Note: I tried to install the OAuth2l from the git link in the Google documents but it was not successful!

Logging in via OAuth gives you a refresh and bearer token. You don't generate it, it is provided to you when you verify the code you were given.

Hopefully, Jeremy has the answer that solves it. If not, edit the question to include "the git link" and the error-message/symptom when the installation is "not successful".

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
